# what other metrics for random search (val_loss, val_accuracy)

Tags: tf.keras

What other metrics can we 'tune' on using keras_tuner Randomsearch?

I'm attempting to use something other than validation loss or validation accuracy as the objective for the tuner. After a bit of research on this, I find myself needing clarification. (Also, I can't find where there is a complete list of the 'string' arguments for the objective parameter. Other metrics I'd like to have available include f1_micro, f1_macro, f1, etc. )

PS: Also, are these metrics calculating per batch? per epoch? or per trial?

```
tuner = keras_tuner.RandomSearch(
    hypermodel=build_model,
    objective = "val_loss",
#    objective="val_accuracy",
    max_trials=10, 
    executions_per_trial=2, 
    directory=f'logs/{datestring:s}',
    project_name="keras_tuned",
    overwrite=True
)
```